# using WinForms Dock with MaximumSize; I want it centered not top left

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I have a PictureBox docked with Fill inside a larger control. The PictureBox is set to scale my image, but I don't want to scale the image larger than the original. Hence, my PictureBox has a maximum size set. As long as the container is smaller than the picture box, the image is fine. As the container expands beyond the maximum size of the PicutreBox, it is obvious that the picture box is tied to the top left. I would rather have the box centered vertically and horizontally in the parent. How do I make the Dock behavior fill from center rather than top left?

Comment: your question is not clear at all.

Comment: All kinds of question like this one **should be** described with some screen shot. The `Fill` behavior **doesn't have** any the so-called `from center` or `top-left`. It will fill the whole your container client area. I think you mean this keyword **Margins**.

Comment: The child control won't fill the whole container area if you set a MaximumSize on the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further thought, I solved the issue with this line of code:

```
_box.SizeChanged += (sender, args) => _box.SizeMode = _box.Width < _cross.Width || _box.Height < _cross.Height ? PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom : PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Layout Anchor* property of the PictureBox. You need to set it to "Top, Left, Bottom, Right" instead of using Dock.Fill. You can set this in the property window for the PictureBox:

[image: position and layout properties]

Advantage of anchors against docking: the (in this case PictureBox) container can be positioned everywhere, but still be relative to other components in the parent panel/container. You can do this using Dock.Fill only with Layouts (different panels).

Comment: There is no advantage of this over that between `Dock` and `Anchor`. They can't replace each other, at least `Dock` is more convenient in many cases.

Comment: I think they are (not always, but) often interchangeable. That is why i see correct positioning in one panel of many components as an advantage.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the Anchor style of None, which will make the control "float" in the middle of the control.  The catch though is that now you have to "initially" center it yourself:

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
pb.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
pb.Image = bmp;
pb.Location = new Point((this.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (pb.Width / 2),
                          (this.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (pb.Height / 2));

this.Controls.Add(pb);
this.AutoScrollMinSize = pb.Size;
```

Comment: This looks good in theory, but out of the box this doesn't seem to work for me. I also tried updating location on the parent's `SizeChanged` event.

Comment: @Brannon You shouldn't update the location with the *parent's* SizeChanged event, but with the PictureBox's SizeChanged event.  And obviously, no docking.

Comment: Without the Dock, what is setting the size on the PictureBox?

Comment: @Brannon You are.  In my example, I just used the size of the image.